# Adding attributes to a model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have four columns in my users database and a config variable. In my view I need to show the sum of those columns divided by the variable - simple enough to calculate but ideally I'd like the result of that to be stored as an attribute on the model.

Basically to avoid doing this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->setPercent();

dd($user->percent);
```

What I'd like to do is have that percent attribute set automatically but I'm not sure where to do that. I've tried overriding the model constructor but that the data for the user hasn't been retrieved at that point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create you just have to add a method like this to your user model:

```
class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function getPercentAttribute($value)
    {
        /// do your magic

        return $yourMagicValue
    }

}
```

To use it the way you said you need:

```
$user->percent
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to have this attribute when the object is created do:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array())
{
    if (!isset($this->percent))
        $this->percent = $this->setPercent();

    parent::__construct($attributes);       
}
```

This works for me